# react-hook-form validation with material-ui - first keystroke not inserted

Tags: reactjs, validation, material-ui, react-hook-form

1. push the submit button [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-sanderson-09g1p?file=/src/Components/App.js) and trigger the "required" validation
2. try to enter a word and pay attention to the first letter of the word that wont be inserted inserted in the textbox

I had to add  `value={formState.surname || ""}`  to the field to avoid the label overlapping the textfield (if you remove `|| ""` will see the issue)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is due to your textfield component that is controlled or uncontrolled if you change `value` by `defaultValue`. It seems to work fine
here the [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-christian-v17xz?file=/src/Components/App.js:824-832).
Your TextArea has to look like this :

```
<TextField
          name="surname"
          onChange={handleChange}
          defaultValue={formState.surname}
          inputRef={register({ required: true, minLength: 5 })}
          variant="outlined"
          label="surname"
/>
```

Comment: you're right but i need to populate this fields on a click button, i've used controlled form for this reason